# Cannot set local storage on iphone safari browser

Tags: javascript, iphone, angularjs, safari

I have an angular website that use many local storage for storage my data. I have tested it on several browsers and devices, all worked. However, it doesn't work on iphone's safari browser, when i checked the local storage and session storage, its empty.

anyone know how to fix this? thx before.

UPDATE NOTE :
Today, I test again with iphone 5 (OS ver 9.1) safari, and it worked well, no bug or error occured. This problem only occured when i tested on iphone 6 (OS ver 9.1) safari. All tests using normal tab.

Comment: What's the size of your data? If you're using private browsing, the browser will not store local storage.

Comment: i am using normal tab... and my data size is less than 2mb...

Answer (score 1):

If you are in private tab on Safari cookies and Local Storage won't work. Please make sure you're viewing your web app using normal tabs.

Comment: Any way for us to see your code? Without it it is kinda hard to tell you why is not working.

Comment: OMG, this is embarassing... i'm really sorry, i dont realize that i used private tab when testing that day... i was sure that i'm not using private tab, but however, when i tested it again with normal tab, it worked... i'm sorry about this foolishness... and thank you for your answer...

Answer (score 1):

Idd in Private modus localstorages is not available however cookies seemes to work in our solution.

We are using [Jstorage](http://www.jstorage.info/) (lastest version has some fixes for detecting availability) in combination with [jQuery-Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#readme) for fallback:

```js
 if ($.jStorage.storageAvailable()) {
   $.jStorage.set('Key', value);
 } else {
   $.cookie('Key', value);
 }
```

NB: Keep in mind that cookies have a limit of 4093 bytes

Comment: sorry, but i am not using private tab... and i cant use your solution, because my data size is larger than 4093 bytes